# css question- cut off box

Tags: css

http://glowing-fire-495.heroku.com/users/3

I was wondering if anyone knows why the tags in the yellow box is cut off like that on the right side?

How can I make it so it doesnt do that?

Comment: does it have a space between pet and care ? If yes try use --- &nbsp; --- between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `margin` and `display` in`#tagsDiv a` to:

```
#tagsDiv a {
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Tested with Firebug, looks alright. The code above will keep it from being cut off, and it'll space them out a little bit so they aren't top-to-bottom.

Comment: hi this works, but then the tags become bigger and then ugly. How can I keep the right side from being cut off while keeping the same size?

Comment: That code shouldn't make them bigger. The `display` makes them wrap around, and the margin adds 2px to all sides, so they aren't crammed together. Can you describe what you mean by "bigger and then ugly"? :P

Comment: yes i think thats what is causing it to be bigger. I am running my application in chrome

Comment: `inline-block` works on Chrome. It doesn't work in IE 6/7, which I suppose could be quite a problem.

Answer (score 2):

add to your css

```
#tagsDiv a {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag is not cut off, there is just an (automatically inserted) line break in its text. Set

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the tag elements.